# how to reload the datatable using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

here is my table

```
    <table class="table table-hover display search dataTable" id="test" cellspacing="0" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> ID </th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody >
    <% all_employees.each do |employee|%>
      <tr>
        <td> <%= check_box_tag 'employee_ids[]', employee.id %> </td>
        <td> <%= employee.name %> </td>
        <td> <%= employee.age %> </td>
        <td> <%= employee.email %> </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and my js

```
function filtered_employee(group_id){
    $.ajax({
      url: "/employee_groups/"+group_id+"/associated_employees",
      type: "get",      
      data: {
        "id" : group_id
      },
      success: function(result) { 
        $('#test').html(result)
      },
      error: function(result){
        $('#test').html(result.responseText)
      }
    });
}
```

Am using Ruby on rails with rails 4 version
on a button click am calling this ajax req am getting the response as expected but when the success is triggered in ajax i get a new table painted over the old one how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest to put your `<table>` within some other container and refresh that container on ajax success as follows:

```
<div class="tableWrapper">
    <table class="table table-hover display search dataTable" id="test" cellspacing="0" >
    ....
    </table>
</div>
```

And JS code:

```
function filtered_employee(group_id){
    $.ajax({
      url: "/employee_groups/"+group_id+"/associated_employees",
      type: "get",      
      data: {
        "id" : group_id
      },
      success: function(result) { 
        $('.tableWrapper').html(result)
      },
      error: function(result){
        $('.tableWrapper').html(result.responseText)
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: i tried in this way too it paints the entire page over the old page(on successful ajax call) in my query it paints only the table

Comment: which view you are returning from `/associated_employees`? In browser's developer console or firebug can you check what is coming back? I mean is it returning entire page with `<html><head><body>` tag or simply response with `<table>` tag?

Comment: entire page <html> to </html> 
the view:
same view show.html where am rendering this table as a partial

Comment: So does that correct behavior? I believe `/associated_employees` should only return view with `<table class="table table-hover display search dataTable" id="test" cellspacing="0">` as starting tag and `</table>` as ending tag